# Julia: using workers(), procs(), etc. inside a module

Tags: julia, mpi

I stumbled across something strage: the various `ClusterManagers` functions and operations, such as `workers()`, `nworkers()`, `procs()`, `nprocs()`, etc. work fine when run a code, unless it's inside a module.

Here's the content of a basic test case `JuliaTest.jl`:

```
using MPI
using ClusterManagers

println(workers(),"     ",nworkers(),"    ",procs(),"     ",nprocs())
```

with `julia -p 3 JuliaTest.jl` I get correct results:

```
[2, 3, 4]     3    [1, 2, 3, 4]     4
```

However, when using the exact same code enclosed in a module:

```
module JuliaTest

using MPI
using ClusterManagers

println(workers(),"     ",nworkers(),"    ",procs(),"     ",nprocs())

end
```

I get errors:

```
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: `workers` not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ ~/JuliaTest.jl:6
in expression starting at /home/JuliaTest.jl:1
```

Is there a reason for this? Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is because the module is not exposed to the `Distributed` package, and adding `using Distributed` solved that.